# In Intellij, when I create new package and after right click new -> java class doesn't show

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

In new Interface package when I right-click in new java class option nit shown

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which of the project templates did you choose when creating the project?

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interface` is not a valid package name, because it is a [Java keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9). A keyword can not be used as an identifier, for example as a package name, variable name or class name. If you choose a different name for your package, the option to create a Java class should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created the module of the **Java** type.